# HttpWebRequest Exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, proxy

I try to do httprequest with asp.net and C#. And I get an exception with message "The Web server refused the connection. The Web server refused the connection"

This is my code:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);    
webRequest.Proxy = proxy; // Proxy's credentials have login and password 

try
{
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        WebResponse resp = e.Response;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And in method webRequest.GetResponse() I get WebException that I read in catch block. str variable contains html-code  that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QIn3.png

Unfortunatelly I can not post images.

How can I fix this error?

P.S. If it is important I use Forefront TMG but I dont know whether it can affect

Comment: You are hitting a 401 page, tell your network admin to give you authorization

Comment: Does your Webserver require authentication, I am seeing proxy in your code ?

Comment: 401 page? What is it? 

>Does your Webserver require authentication

how can i check it? I use IIS 7.5